# How to connect an iPhone app (rest) to XAMPP using a local WIFI connection?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, apache, xampp

I'm making an iPhone app communicating (REST) with a PHP web app on wordpress on my local server using XAMPP (version 7.2.7-0).

The problem is that I can't reach my local server with my phone whereas I use to do it using the address http://localhost:8080.

I already tried several things I found on this forum an others:

- connect using "http://my_mac_name.local:8080"
- connect using my computer IP address "http://192.168.X.X:8080
- modify httpd.conf, httpd-xampp.conf
- include the httpd-host.conf file with a virtual host as I found on another forum...

Not sure I did it in the good order or correctly, so don't think it cannot be the solution to use those solutions

I should reach my XAMPP local server on my Mac using my iPhone. I know it is possible, but I don't know really know how...

Edit: 
I checked which ports are open on the different IP adresses using the app "Network utility":

- 192.168.64.2 (XAMPP): 80 is open
- 127.0.0.1: 8080 is open
- 192.168.X.X my computer's local IP address: NOTHING

Maybe should I try to open the port 8080 on my local address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a software named SquidMan to create a proxy. The procedure is described here: http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/

Advices:

- do not use your localhost port in your proxy's settings (I used 8000 instead of 8080)
- add an URL associated to your localhost in your /etc/hosts like "127.0.0.1 my_local_website"
- It seems that sometimes you have to restart your computer for SquidMan to take into account your setting

Answer (score 0):

If they're already on the same wifi network then you should be able to reach it through the host PC's IP Address.

Maybe if that doesn't work try and connect the computer to a hotspot on your phone (no internet needed) and it should show you a list of connected devices with their IP addresses and you can hard code that value in your app.

Comment: Thank for your answer.

I connected my computer to my phone and tried to connect my local website using the new IP address ( and "http://my_mac_name.local:8080") but it does not work neither.

I just want to precise that my httpd files are as I got them when I installed XAMPP ( I removed every changes)